# Configuring Application Verifier to generate a full-memory .DMP file?

Tags: winapi, postmortem-debugging

Under AppVerifier, one of our apps blows up. I get a DMP file, but it's a minidump. Specifically, while I've got the call stack, I'd also like the user-space memory for the faulting process (it uses a lot of globals). How do I configure App Verifier (or Windows) to give me a full dump file?

Comment: Which specific classes of information/data are missing from the minidumps that you're seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to configure Windows itself (or more precise, the windows error reporting component) to generate full dumps.

See this KB article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254649/

For Server2008, Vista SP1:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181.aspx

Comment: Are there equivalent instructions for Vista/2008?

Comment: The first link configures kernel dumps for bluescreens. How does this relate to the question about user mode dumps?